# Ask `ts` to print timestamps relative to binary start time?

Tags: bash, timestamps

Is it possible to make `ts` print timestamps relative to when the binary was started, rather than wall clock time? I usually use it to measure time taken between events in a single command run, so wall clock time isn't very interesting; relative time is, mainly to when the command started running. Other solutions to get the same behavior is also appreciated.

e.g. `some --command=or 'something' | ts '%.T'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least with the [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) implementation, there is a `-s` option for that:

> ```
>    If the -i or -s switch is passed, ts timestamps incrementally instead.
>    In case of -i, every timestamp will be the time elapsed since the last
>    timestamp. In case of -s, the time elapsed since start of the program
>    is used.  The default format changes to "%H:%M:%S", and "%.S" and "%.s"
>    can be used as well.
> ```

Ex.

```
$ while : ; do printf '...\n'; sleep 1; done | ts
May 11 15:42:41 ...
May 11 15:42:42 ...
May 11 15:42:43 ...
May 11 15:42:44 ...
^C
```

but

```
$ while : ; do printf '...\n'; sleep 1; done | ts -s
00:00:00 ...
00:00:01 ...
00:00:02 ...
00:00:03 ...
00:00:04 ...
^C
```